# Custom post metabox with upload file button

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custom meta filed with upload file functionality but the problem is I can't get the fileurl button value when hit "insert into Post" below are my jQuery code

```
window.send_to_editor = function(html) 

    {
        dlink = jQuery('button.urlfile',html).attr('title');
        jQuery('#download_link').val(dlink);
        tb_remove();
    }


    tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?post_id=1&amp;type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
    return false;
```

Tried also this code search from internet but nothing happen it doesent get the File URL

```
window.send_to_editor = function(html){
    dlink = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
    jQuery('#download_link').val(dlink);
    tb_remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second version uses and image source, so that won't work with a file upload.

```
dlink = jQuery(html).attr('href');
```

Should work.